# How to check whether the letters of a string exist in the given order within another string?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to make a program to check whether the word `"nadia"` is present with this sequence in a string. if you can delete zero or more characters to get this word then you should print `"YES"` else print `"NO"`. Can anyone help me find what are the test cases that I am missing? When I try to submit it, it says wrong output.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool nadiaFound(string s){
    int counter = 0;
    char key[5] = { 'n', 'a', 'd', 'i', 'a' };
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        if (s[i] == key[counter]){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter == 5){
        return true;
    }
    else { return false; }
}
int main(){
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    string *names = new string[T];

    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++){
        cin >> names[i];
    }
    bool *barr = new bool[T];

    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++){
        barr[i] = false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++){
        if (nadiaFound(names[i])){
            barr[i] = true;
        }
        else{
            barr[i] = false;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++){
        if (barr[i]){
            cout << "YES" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "NO" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's bad form to use an upper case letter to represent an int, especially a T, which had me scanning your code for a template definition.

Comment: @Simon if the string contains nadia without changing the order of characters

Comment: So `Anadia`, `nadiaA` and `nadAia` should all match?

Comment: yes but if you change this sequence it doesnt match like "ndaia , nxzdia .. etc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may access out of bound memory while accessing `key[counter]` causing undefined behaviour. One possible fix is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
    if (s[i] == key[counter]){
        if(++counter == 5) break;
        // ^^        ^^^^  ^^^^^
    }
}
```

or rewrite `for` as `for (int i = 0; i < s.size() && counter < 5; i++)`

Comment: ...or `if (++counter == 5) return true;`, and have simply a `return false;` below the loop.

Answer (score 2):

This can also work:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string names; 
    getline(cin,names); 
    cout << names << endl;
    if (names.find("a", names.find("i", names.find("d", names.find("a", names.find("n", 0))))) != string::npos)
        cout << "YES" << endl;
    else
        cout << "NO" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result returned by the functions **find** points to the first location within the string where the searched string begins or where the searched char is located (depending on the variant).

If the search failed, both functions return a special value denoted as `string::npos` (This value, when used as the value for a len (or sublen) parameter in string's member functions, means "until the end of the string".). You can use it to check if your haystack contained the desired find.